# how to find order of rows in a matrix using order function

Tags: r

d<-matrix(1:25,5,5) (this is just an example, the numbers will be random essentially)

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25
```

I would like to apply order to each row, and get something like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 
...
```

I tried this:

```
l<-apply(d,1, function(x) order(x))
```

But I get this result:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4
[5,]    5    5    5    5    5
```

Example 2:

```
> d<-matrix(sample(1:25),5,5)
> d
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1   20   13    4   11
[2,]   22   17   24    3   16
[3,]   18   23    2   15   14
[4,]    5   25    7   10   21
[5,]   12    8    6   19    9
```

Sorry I'm thinking of rank. The result should be something like this:

1 5 4 2 3 (row 1) and so on:

Please help, thank you!!

Comment: You need to `t` the `l` i.e. `t(l)`

Comment: that doesn't work if you try d<-matrix(sample(25),5,5) @akrun

Comment: What is the expected output in that.  Also, use `set.seed` for making this reproducible.

Comment: @akrun please see example 2 above, sorry im thinking of rank. would it be possible to get whole rank numbers? i see that i can get decimals too?

Comment: You can use `rank` with `ties.method` specified

Comment: Try  `res <- t(apply(d, 1, rank));  res[1,]
#[1] 1 5 4 2 3`

Comment: thanks a lot, that was very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rank`

```
 res <- t(apply(d, 1, rank))
 res
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 #[1,]    1    5    4    2    3
 #[2,]    4    3    5    1    2
 #[3,]    4    5    1    3    2
 #[4,]    1    5    2    3    4
 #[5,]    4    2    1    5    3
```